# Php search script to search all values in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table of books which has info such as bname, bauthor, bdetails...etc

I want to provide a php script to search any thing from the table ...i tried a few scripts but it didnt work ..

Also i want to provide the option to provide option of selecting category ...

if the category is not selected then also the script should run...

Can anyone help me in this please ...
..

I m trying this :

```
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

 $result = mysql_query($data);


if (!$result) die ("DAtabase acces faild bc : ". mysql_error());


echo " <ul class=listbk>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   


    echo "  <li class=bkd><a href=details.php?bid=".$row['pid']. "> <img src=images/".$row['bname']. ".jpg />
      <ul class=showcasetitle> <span> ". $row['bname'] . " </span> </ul>
          <p align=center style=text-align:center; font-size:10px;> By    <span> ". $row['bauthor'] . "</span></p>
      </a>          <p align=center style=text-align:center; color: #F00;><span class=WebRupee style=color: #F00;>&#x20B9;</span> ". $row['price'] . "  only !!!</span></p>
</li> " ;



    }

echo " </ul> ";
```

Comment: show your code and it´s easier to help you

Comment: See the question , I have inserted the query which i am trying .

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $text = 'John';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE MATCH(`bname`,`bauthor`,`bdetails`) AGAINST ('".$text."')";
?>
```